# Swift: Create utility methods as static class or regular functions?

Tags: swift

Coming from Java we often create utility methods as:

```
class Util {
    public static doSomething(...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

In Swift it seems you can do the same with `static func`

```
class Util {
     static func doSomething(...) {
         ....
     }
}
```

But then you can also just do a stand alone function in Swift which is not not within a class.

```
func doSomething(...) {
      ....
}
```

What is the best practice?  Is this subjective or there is a reason why you must pick one or the other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is largely subjective and there is no reason why you must pick one over the other.

That being said, some people favor the static method approach for organizational reasons, or as a form of namespacing. For example, using the static method approach also allows you to have a method `ClassA.doSomething()` and a method named `ClassB.doSomething()`.